# GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP рисует не правильно

Tags: android, opengl, opengles

Хочу нарисовать на экране вот такую фигуру

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу это сделать с помощью восьми вершин и `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`

Рисую отдельно верхний квадрат

```
private float[] mTableVerticesWithTriangles = { //
//          // Top
        -0.5f, 0.5f, //
        -0.5f, 0f, //
        0.5f, 0.5f,//
        0.5f, 0f//

};

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(final GL10 iGL10)
{
    //Clear the rendering surface
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    //Table Top
    glUniform4f(mUColorLocation, .5f, .5f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

потом отдельно рисую нижний

```
private float[] mTableVerticesWithTriangles = { //
//           Top
//          -0.5f, 0.5f, //
//          -0.5f, 0f, //
//          0.5f, 0.5f,//
//          0.5f, 0f//

//            Bottom
        -0.5f, 0f, //
        -0.5f, -0.5f, //
        0.5f, 0f,//
        0.5f, -0.5f,//

};

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(final GL10 iGL10)
{
    //Clear the rendering surface
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

//      //Table Top
//      glUniform4f(mUColorLocation, .5f, .5f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
//      glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

    //Table Bottom
    glUniform4f(mUColorLocation, .5f, 1.0f, .5f, .5f);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
}
```

Получается вот такое

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь соединяю все вместе

```
private float[] mTableVerticesWithTriangles = { //
//           Top
        -0.5f, 0.5f, //
        -0.5f, 0f, //
        0.5f, 0.5f,//
        0.5f, 0f//

//            Bottom
        -0.5f, 0f, //
        -0.5f, -0.5f, //
        0.5f, 0f,//
        0.5f, -0.5f,//

};

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(final GL10 iGL10)
{
    //Clear the rendering surface
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    //Table Top
    glUniform4f(mUColorLocation, .5f, .5f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

    //Table Bottom
    glUniform4f(mUColorLocation, .5f, 1.0f, .5f, .5f);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 4, 4);
}
```

и вот что получается

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что делаю не так?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас перед комментом //bottom нет запятой, и вместо двух флоатов 0 и - 0.5 вы получаете один - 0.5, и у нижнего прямоугольника x и y координаты меняются местами